# Insert Into Select From Where Between [Latest Data's Date] And [Now]

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012, sql-insert, insert-into

I am trying to run the query shown below in order to copy all data from the RemoteServer to the LocalServer that is between the date of the latest time-stamped record and the exact time when I execute the query.

```
INSERT INTO [LocalServer].[database1].[dbo].[Table1]
SELECT * FROM [RemoteServer].[database1].[dbo].[Table1]
WHERE TimeCol BETWEEN MAX(TimeCol) and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

However, running this query results in the following error:

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

What is this error message talking about? What is the query I am looking for to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Post more details of what you are attempting to do. It isn't clear from the invalid SQL you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use MAX() in WHERE because it's an aggregate function. Use HAVING() instead. Is this what you want?

```
INSERT INTO [LocalServer].[database1].[dbo].[Table1]
SELECT * FROM [RemoteServer].[database1].[dbo].[Table1]
WHERE TimeCol BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(TimeCol) FROM 
[LocalServer].[database1].[dbo].[Table1]) and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Edited based on Martin Smith's comment

Comment: I presume the `TimeCol` they are trying to reference is in the local server table as that is the only thing that makes sense. - i.e. get records since the last synchronisation.

Comment: And if that interpretation of what they want/guess is correct then probably they need `>` rather than `BETWEEN` to avoid pulling over records twice when they were the last imported the previous batch. And debatable whether the `<=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` would be needed in that case to except if they are logging dates in the future.

Comment: Upon using the above code, the statement executed perfectly. Thank you.